# How could I change the socket.io chat app so it uses external javascript and css files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I did the demo for the socket.io chat app, but in the demo, there is javascript/jquery and css inline in the html file. How could I modify this app so that the inline script and the css could be in an external files that are sent to and used by the client?

Here is the server code:

```
//index.js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And here is the html: (I added a comment where the script that I want to be in a separate js file starts)

```
//index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <header>
      <center>
      <h1>
        Socket.IO Chat App
      </h1>
      <h4>
      Commands: "/nick" to set nickname, "/join" to join/create chatroom, "/leave" to leave chatroom
    </h4>
    </center>
    </header>

    //HERE IS THE CSS THAT I WANT TO BE IN A SEPARATE FILE:
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #ddd; }
      body { background-color: white; color: black;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>

  //HERE IS THE JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY THAT I WANT TO BE IN A SEPARATE FILE:
  <script>
    var nick = "";
    var room = "";
    $(function () {
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        var message = {
          nick: nick,
          room: room,
          message: $('#m').val()
        };
        if(($('#m').val()).startsWith("/nick ")){
          nick = ($('#m').val()).slice(6) + ": ";
          message.nick = nick;
          console.log(nick);
        }
        else if(($('#m').val()).startsWith("/join ")){
          room = ($('#m').val()).slice(6);
          message.room = room;
          console.log(room);
        }
        else if(($('#m').val()).startsWith("/leave")){
          room = "";
          message.room = room;
          console.log(room);
        }
        else{
        socket.emit('chat message', message);}
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log("Message from " + msg.nick + " in room " + msg.room + " saying: " + msg.message);
        if(msg.room == room){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg.nick + " " + msg.message));
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just move all that code to a file and use `<script src="URL of that file"></script>`.

Comment: Why do you think this would be any different from some other external JS file?

Comment: And the same with the CSS.

Comment: When I try that I get: GET http://localhost:3000/app.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: That message seems clear, you either put the file in the wrong place, or you gave the wrong URL. Are you sure you put it in the same document root as the HTML?

Comment: Ok, they are both in the same folder, and I replaced the script with:

<script src="/app.js"></script> and I am still getting that error

Comment: It should be `src="app.js"`. The `/` means to look in the root folder, not the same folder.

Comment: I tried that and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Then you must not have put it in the same folder, because that should definitely work. Check the server log to see where it's looking for the file.

Comment: Why do you have `<header>` inside `<head>`? Anything that's supposed to render on the page should be in `<body>`.

Comment: As you can see, I am new to this! They are definitely in the same folder because there is only one folder holding all of the files and the node_modules folder. I will keep messing around to try and figure out what's wrong, thanks!

Comment: There's obviously more than one folder, for instance there's the `/socket.io` folder that contains `socket.io.js`

Comment: I do not even see that folder, all I see is app.js, index.html, index.js, package.json, and then the node_modules folder so I'm not sure where socket.io.js is located.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. You're not getting an error for `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js">` so it must be finding that file somewhere. Maybe you have rewrite rules configured on your server.

Comment: Ok thank you for the help!

Comment: Insert `app.use(express.static('public'))` before `app.get`